Multiprocessing pool stops operating - Windows 11
The following code start 5 multiprocessing tasks. Those tasks print a message then go to sleep a random period of time then do this again. That is repeated 10 time so the entire set of tasks should complete in about 50 seconds at most.
When the pool is first created, the addresses of the 5 pool objects are printed.
This code works fine, but it was terminated before it completed all its work. When it is run again, you can see new addresses are assigned for the 5 pool objects.
After this process of stopping the operation before it is done (keyboard interrupt), several times, the code stops working. The tasks are never created and the code falls right through to the end. And the allocation of pool objects show that they are allocating the same objects over and over whereas before new object addresses where assigned.
So it appears that OS resources are being allocated and never released. And when those resources are all used up, the code stops working. But even when this command prompt it is running under is terminated (its window closed down), those resources are not being returned. And when a new command prompts is open and the app run again, you can see the same object IDs being assigned, the tasks are never started, and the code falls though. Normally the code stops at the pool.join() waiting for the workers (task) to complete.
There does not seem to be a way to get the OS to release these pool resources. The only way is to restart the OS.
During debugging of code, it is unlikely that one would ever have it run to completion and to have the pool.close() and poll.join() executed. SO after a few execution of the code being tested, no more tasks are allocated.
Thus the question - how do we ensure the spawned off tasks are terminated and their resources returned to the pool?
import multiprocessing
import time
import random

# Simultaneous tasks running
def task(id):
    for i in range(10):
        stime = random.randint(1,5)
        print(f"Task {id}: Woke up. Now sleep {stime}")
        time.sleep(stime)
    exit(0)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ('create pool of tasks')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
    print (pool)
    
    # Start 5 asynchronous tasks
    for i in range(1,6):
        result = pool.apply_async(task, i)
        print (result)

    pool.close()
    
    # Wait for all tasks to complete
    pool.join()
    print ('end program')


When I run your program, I never see the output from the print statement in the task function.  The reason for that is explained by tdelaney in his answer.  But your verbal description of how the program behaves is different from what I see, and apparently different from what tdelaney sees.  Why is that?  Is the code you presented the exact  code you are running?

I would have expected your IDE to warn you about the misuse of apply_async. The args argument needs to be an iterable of arguments to pass to the task.
Here's how you could get the results you require:
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep
from random import randint

def task(id_):
    for _ in range(10):
        stime = randint(1, 5)
        print(f"Task {id_}: Woke up. Now sleep {stime}")
        sleep(stime)

def main():
    pool = Pool()
    try:
        for i in range(1, 6):
            pool.apply_async(task, args=(i,))
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Common practice is to use a tuple which, obviously, is iterable. But you could use a list, a dictionary or a set (although that might be a bit esoteric).
e.g.,
pool.apply_async(task, args=[i])
pool.apply_async(task, args={i:None})
pool.apply_async(task, args={i})

All three variants would produce the same results in this case

I noted in an answer that I did not correctly post the code showing the issue and incorrectly did not specify an iterable object to the apply_async function. But my real purpose of posting the question, was the fact that when I ran the real and correct code repeatedly and aborted it while it was running, eventually it stopped working.
But I have now put the entire work of the 'task' function into a try/except block so now when I abort the code from a keyboard interrupt while it is running, it can handle the interrupt and each of the spawned off tasks properly terminate and the final pool.join() is executed and all resources are properly returned. Now orphan tasks are left running.
In this example, the spawned tasks eventually terminate so resources would be returned even if the tasks became orphans. But in the project where this code will be used, those tasks never end as they use events to wake them up when there is work to do and otherwise they sleep waiting for an event. So if those tasks were not forced to end, they could hang as orphans forever.
